# No diff output in interactive staging

Tags: git, git-diff

I get normal `git diff` output on the command line without problem:

```
--- a/my_file.rb
+++ b/my_file.rb
@@ -108,6 +108,8 @@ my_block do
     #unchanged line
     #unchanged line
     #unchanged line
+    #new line
+    #new line
     #unchanged line
(END)
```

However in interactive staging mode I get nothing:

```
> git add -i my_file.rb
staged     unstaged path
  1:    unchanged        +2/-0 my_file.rb

*** Commands ***
  1: status       2: update       3: revert       4: add untracked
  5: patch        6: diff         7: quit         8: help
What now> 6
*** Commands ***
  1: status       2: update       3: revert       4: add untracked
  5: patch        6: diff         7: quit         8: help
What now>
```

I assume git is trying to use some command for output that it's not finding, something other than `less` which is working fine for normal diff. What is it or where do I specify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [git-add(1)](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#_interactive_mode):

> **diff**
>
> This lets you review what will be committed (i.e. between HEAD and index).

Since you did not add anything yet, the diff is empty. In contrast `git-diff` compares HEAD with the working directory. The call from the interactive add is akin to `git diff --cached`.